# How to build a MANIFEST file for a Perl module

Tags: perl, perl-module

I create some modules without using `Module::Starter` :(.
I need to build a `MANIFEST` file to run my tests.
Should I do it by hand, or is there an automated way to build it ?

Comment: I can't delete my accepted answer, but there is a better answer. So, please go accept the other one. Otherwise, my answer is going to keep getting downvoted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run `make manifest` or `./Build manifest`, depending on the build tool.

It will call `mkmanifest` for you.

Comment: Whether or not Module::Starter was used, if there is a Makefile.PL or Build.PL written by hand, then this is a good recommendation.

Comment: True. I guess I took the question too literally. This is definitely a better answer (although I don't think my answer needed to be voted down).

Comment: I'm a little newbie with this. If I just call make manifest I get : `nothing to be done for manifest`

Answer (score 7):

You can create manifest using [ExtUtils::Manifest](http://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/Manifest.html) package:

```
perl -MExtUtils::Manifest=mkmanifest -e 'mkmanifest()'
```

This oneliner will create manifest in current dir. It also will use `MANIFEST.SKIP` if you have one.

Answer (score 4):

If you install [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla), you can set up a simple `dist.ini` file and then run `dzil build`. That will create a MANIFEST and other necessary files for releasing a distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is [ExtUtils::Manifest](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::Manifest):

> mkmanifest
>
> ```
>    mkmanifest();
> ```
>
> Writes all files in and below the current directory to your MANIFEST. It works similar to the result of the Unix command
>
> ```
>    find . > MANIFEST
> ```
>
> All files that match any regular expression in a file MANIFEST.SKIP (if it exists) are ignored.
>
> Any existing MANIFEST file will be saved as MANIFEST.bak.

For example:

```
$ perl -mExtUtils::Manifest=mkmanifest -e 'mkmanifest()'
```

Comment: This answer helped but I had to do it like this on the bash command line : `perl -e 'use ExtUtils::Manifest qw(mkmanifest); mkmanifest();'`